# Deduct Health Care Premiums for Family When Employer Only Pays for Me

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance

My employer offers insurance coverage, pays a substantial amount for me, but pays nothing for my spouse or my children.  The difference in cost is around $127/month for myself and $1,330/month if I want to insure the entire family.

To save money, we're going with private insurance for my wife and the kids, which costs around $600/month.

My questions is whether or not I can use the cost of the premiums for my wife and kids ($600/month) as an out of pocket medical expense or some other deduction.

I've read some on the topic, and it sounded like I might be able to because my employer doesn't subsidize their insurance.

Answer (score 3):

You can deduct what you pay for your own and your family's health insurance regardless of whether it is subsidized by your employer or not, as well 
as all other medical and
dental expenses for your family, as an *itemized deduction*
on Schedule A of Form 1040, but only to the extent that the 
total exceeds 7.5% of your Adjusted Gross Income (AGI)
([10%](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc502.html) on tax returns for year 2013 onwards).
As pointed out in KeithB's comment, you cannot deduct
any health insurance premium (or other medical expense)
that was paid for out of pre-tax dollars, nor indeed
can you deduct any medical expense to the extent that 
it was paid for by the insurance company directly to
hospital or doctor (or reimbursed to you) for
a covered expense; e.g. if the insurance company reimbursed
you $72 for a claim for a doctor's visit for which you
paid $100 to the doctor, only $28 goes on Schedule A
to be added to the amount that you will be comparing
to the 7.5% of AGI threshold, and the $72 is not
income to you that needs to be reported on Form 1040.
Depending on other items on Schedule A, your total itemized
deductions might not exceed the standard deduction, in which
case you will likely choose to use the standard deduction.
In this case, you "lose" the deduction for medical expenses
as well as all other expenses deductible on Schedule A.

> **Summary of some of the discussions in the comments**
>   Health care insurance premiums **cannot** be paid for
>   from HSA accounts (IRS Pub 969, page 8, column 2, near
>   the bottom) though there are some exceptions.  Nor
>   can health care insurance premiums be paid from an
>   FSA account (IRS Pub 969, page 17, column 1, near the top).

If you have a business on the side and file a Schedule C
as a self-employed person, you can buy medical insurance
for that business's employees (and their families
too, if you like) as an employment benefit, and pay for it out of
the income of the Schedule C business, (thus saving on taxes).
But be aware that if you have employees
other than yourself in the side business, they would need
to be covered by the same policy too.  You can even
decide to pay all medical expenses of your
employees and their
families too (no 7.5% limitation there!) as an employment
benefit but again, you
cannot discriminate against other employees (if any)
of the Schedule C business in this matter.  Of course,
all this money that reduced your Schedule C income
does not go on Schedule A at all.

If your employer *permits* your family to be covered under
its health insurance plan (for a cost, of course), check
whether you are allowed to pay for the insurance with
*pre-tax* dollars.  The private (non-Schedule C)
insurance would, of course,
be paid for with post-tax dollars.  I would doubt that 
you would be able to save enough money on taxes to make
up the difference between $1330/month and $600/month, but
it might also be that the private insurance policy covers
a lot less than your employer's policy does.  As a rule of
thumb, group insurance through an employer can be expected
to offer better coverage than privately purchased insurance.
Whether the added coverage is worth the additional cost is a 
different matter.  But while considering this matter,
keep in mind that privately purchased insurance is not 
always guaranteed
to be renewable, and a company might decline to renew a
policy if there were a large number of claims. A replacement
policy might not cover pre-existing conditions for some
time (six months? a year?) or maybe even permanently.  So,
do consider these aspects as well.  Of course, an employer
can also change health insurance plans or drop them
entirely as an employment benefit (or you might quit
and go work for a different company), but as long as
the employer's health plan is in
existence, you (and continuing members of your
family) cannot be discriminated against and denied
coverage under the employer's plan.

Comment: This is very good and thorough. A point of clarification. In the first sentence, it should be clarified that it applies to only post-tax expenses, not anything taken out by your employer pretax.  So pretax premiums are not deductible, but post-tax copays are.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the point about only post-tax and non-reimbursed expenses going on Schedule A.

Comment: the 7.5% becomes 10% limit next year

Comment: I'm not sure. I think 2012 returns, but I haven't seen anything definitive from the IRS yet...

Comment: Aren't insurance premiums paid outside an employer's plan payable from a flex account? That should be good for $5000 worth of expense being pulled pretax. Until congress screws it up.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Health insurance premiums and long term care insurance premiums cannot be paid from FSAs and HSAs. These premiums are specifically mentioned as not being eligible to be paid from these flexible accounts.

Comment: From Pub 969 "Qualified medical expenses are those specified in the plan that would generally qualify for the medical and dental expenses deduction. These are explained in Publication 502, Medical and Dental Expenses." From Pub 502 - "Medical expenses include the premiums you pay for insurance that covers the expenses of medical care, and the amounts you pay for transportation to get medical care." Of course, it's not eligible if paid pretax already, as are my premiums for my employer's health plan. My comment was for the outside plan.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer _Premiums_ for privately purchased health insurance are _specifically_ excluded as being eligible to be paid from a FSA or HSA plan even though these premiums are deductible (subject to 7.5% floor) on Schedule A as a medical expense along with anything else listed in other IRS Pubs as qualified medical expense. Congress specifically pulled out premiums as something you either pay for with pretax dollars for your employer's health plan, or pay for private insurance with post-tax dollars but get to deduct (subject to the 7.5% (soon to be 10%) floor) on Schedule A.

Comment: Dilip - Citation? I quoted from IRS pubs. (I am open to the fact that I may be wrong, just looking for written confirmation)

Comment: I believe they are assuming that the premium paid is through an employer sponsored plan, and therefore (the employee copay) withheld pre-tax. I agree. I still refer you to the IRS pub specifically stating it's an allowed expense.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Pub 969, page 8, column 2, near the bottom.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Pub 969, page 17, near the top of column 1

Comment: Pub 969 p17, as Dilip cites - "You cannot receive distributions from your FSA for the following expenses.
• Amounts paid for health insurance premiums." I stand corrected, humbled, and better informed.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Based on the comments here, you may want to edit [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/11689) where you state that you can use an FSA for the premiums. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez - Wow, great catch, Zuly! I just edited that response thanks to you.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer No problem! I'm researching the topic and happen to have stumbled across both questions at the same time.